# java.lang.ClassCastException: Entity A incompatible with Entity B

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to get proficient in generics in Java. I have some 100 entities that use the same findBy method in JPA interface. Almost all of them require a call to AwrSnapDetails so instead of adding 
`@ManyToOne private AwrSnapDetails awrSnapDetails;` to each Entity, I've created a HelperEntity class and using `@Embedded` annotation. Now I have gotten to the point in coding where I can't figure out what I am doing wrong and how to go about resolving this error.

**Entity**

```
@Entity
public class AwrMemStats {
    String description;
    double begin_;
    double end_;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;

    @Embedded
    private HelperEntity helperEntity;


    public AwrMemStats() {

    }

    public AwrMemStats(String description, double begin_, double end_, AwrSnapDetails awrSnapDetails) {
        this.description = description;
        this.begin_ = begin_;
        this.end_ = end_;
        HelperEntity h = new HelperEntity(awrSnapDetails);
    }
    // getters/setters removed for clarity

}
```

**Embedded Entity**

```
@Embeddable
public class HelperEntity implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManyToOne
    AwrSnapDetails awrSnapDetails;

    public HelperEntity() {
    }


    public HelperEntity(AwrSnapDetails awrSnapDetails) {
        super();
        this.awrSnapDetails = awrSnapDetails;
    }




    public AwrSnapDetails getAwrSnapDetails() {
        return awrSnapDetails;
    }

    public AwrSnapDetails setAwrSnapDetails(AwrSnapDetails awrSnapDetails) {
        return this.awrSnapDetails = awrSnapDetails;
    }
}
```

**Service Class**

```
@Service
public class HelperService<T> {

    @Autowired 
    private HelperRepository<T> repository;

    public void add(T entity) {
        repository.save(entity);
    }
    public void add(List<T> entities) {
        repository.saveAll(entities);
    }

    public T get(T entity) {
        T t = repository.findByHelperEntityAwrSnapDetailsStartSnapIdAndHelperEntityAwrSnapDetailsInstanceDetailDbNameAndHelperEntityAwrSnapDetailsInstanceDetailDbId(
                ((HelperEntity) entity).getAwrSnapDetails().getStartSnapId(), 
                ((HelperEntity) entity).getAwrSnapDetails().getInstanceDetail().getDbName(), 
                ((HelperEntity) entity).getAwrSnapDetails().getInstanceDetail().getDbId());
                //((AwrMemStats) entity).getHelperEntity().getAwrSnapDetails().getStartSnapId(), 
                //((AwrMemStats) entity).getHelperEntity().getAwrSnapDetails().getInstanceDetail().getDbName(), 
                //((AwrMemStats) entity).getHelperEntity().getAwrSnapDetails().getInstanceDetail().getDbId());
        if (t!= null) {
            return t;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
public class HelperController<T> {

    @Autowired
    private HelperService<T> service;

    public void add(T entity) {
        service.add(entity);
    }
    public void add(List<T> entities) {
        service.add(entities);
    }
    public T get(T entity) {
        return service.get(entity);

    }
}
```

**Execution**
getAwrSnapDetails() initilized in HelperLoader

```
@Component
public class LoadAwrMemStats extends HelperLoader{
@Autowired
    private HelperController<AwrMemStats> controller;
public void doThis() {
AwrMemStats profile = new AwrMemStats("a",1.0,1.0,getAwrSnapDetails());
AwrMemStats s = controller.get(profile);
```

ANd finally the **ERROR message**

```
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.mharoon.perfmon.awr.entities.AwrMemStats incompatible with net.mharoon.perfmon.awr.entities.HelperEntity
    at net.mharoon.perfmon.awr.service.HelperService.get(HelperService.java:27)
    at net.mharoon.perfmon.awr.controller.HelperController.get(HelperController.java:24)
    ...
    ...
```

**Update** this code works but only for given class AwrMemStats.

```
public List<T> get(T entity) {
        List<T> ts = repository.findByHelperEntityAwrSnapDetailsStartSnapIdAndHelperEntityAwrSnapDetailsInstanceDetailDbIdAndHelperEntityAwrSnapDetailsInstanceDetailDbName(
                //((HelperEntity) entity).getAwrSnapDetails().getStartSnapId(), 
                //((HelperEntity) entity).getAwrSnapDetails().getInstanceDetail().getDbName(), 
                //((HelperEntity) entity).getAwrSnapDetails().getInstanceDetail().getDbId());
                ((AwrMemStats) entity).getHelperEntity().getAwrSnapDetails().getStartSnapId(), 
                ((AwrMemStats) entity).getHelperEntity().getAwrSnapDetails().getInstanceDetail().getDbId(), 
                ((AwrMemStats) entity).getHelperEntity().getAwrSnapDetails().getInstanceDetail().getDbName());
        if (!ts.isEmpty()) {
            return ts;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are returning an Object that is not AwrMemStats and assigning it to AwrMemStats.
A simple work around is to replace

```
public T get(T entity)
```

with

```
public <T extends AwrMemStats> T get(T entity)
```

EDIT : Another solution (which is more generic) is..

replace

```
public class AwrMemStats
```

with

```
public class AwrMemStats extends HelperEntity
```

then replace

```
AwrMemStats s = controller.get(profile);
```

with

```
AwrMemStats s = (AwrMemStats) controller.get(profile);
```

Comment: thanks laserany. As `get(T entity)` is in generic Helper service, how will It handle for another entity class say `AwrHostStats`. I was hoping that all entities share `HelperEntity` that I could use that for retrieving database details

Comment: for each entity class that you have, make them extend the HelperEntity class (for example public class AwrHostStats extends HelperEntity) then when you want to create a new AwrHostStats object cast it. For example AwrHostStats awrHostStats = (AwrHostStats) controller.get(profile);

Comment: That did the trick with few additional modifications. 1. Add the `@MappedSuperclass` to HelperEntity, otherwise it doesn't add the foreignkey relationship. 2. Casting to `(AwrMemStats) controller.get(profile);` was not required